# AJAX Internal server error

Tags: ajax

I couldnt find out what is the error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#btnsumbit").click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: '{"username":"' + $("input#txtuser").val() + '","password":"' + $("input#txtpwd").val() + '"}',
                     url: 'http://localhost:53179/hdfcmobile/WebService.asmx/Login_Data',
                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                     dataType: 'json',

                     success:
                  function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

                      var status = data.Status;
                      alert(data.d);




                  },
                     error:
                  function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert(textStatus);
                  }

                 });

             });
         });


    </script>
```

I am getting 500 internal server error.How to call this webservice.I have passes the method with the url.Thanks for any help...

Comment: could you please give your server side code for Login_Data method ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the way you are sending is wrong, send it like this

```
data:  {

    "username": $("input#txtuser").val(),
    "password": $("input#txtpwd").val()

}
```

Next make sure, url: `http://localhost:53179/hdfcmobile/WebService.asmx/Login_Data` is returning JSON output.